# How to check if an object inside an array is still there

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a project where objects are stored in an array. People can remove objects manually, but now I want to make so when an object is created it will be removed from the array after 5 seconds, only if it's still there (not manually removed). I'm using a settimeout where the object is spliced. How to do this that it will only remove the object if it's still there?

Edit:

So I wasn't very clear, when the timeout removes an object and it's not there anymore it just removes the next one like you'd expect.

Here's my code for remove the object manually:

```
     if (intersect(player, food)) {

            foods.splice(i, 1);
        }
```

Here's the code of creating and removing with a timer:

```
       food = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
    };

     foods.push(foods[i]);

    setTimeout(function(){

        foods.splice(i, 1);


    }, 10000);
```

Comment: Share your code also

Comment: code please.......

Comment: Provide us with the code that you have tried and tell us what it doesn't do that you want it to. Show us your effort and only then can we help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the index of the object in the array..

`Array.indexOf()` // returns -1 if its not there

```
function addToArrayAndRemoveAfter(object, array, removeAfterMs) {
   array.push(object)

   // remove after ms
   setTimeout(() => {
     var idx = array.indexOf(object);
     idx > -1 && array.splice(idx, 1)
   }, removeAfterMs)
}
```

Please add your code next time your asking something:

> Its almost much harder to parse code out of human written text, then vice versa